# int variable = sentence.Length won't work but sentence.Length will

Tags: c#, string

The objective of the code is to remove the positions where there are 2+ spaces together, and replace them with a single space.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        int size = Convert.ToInt16(sentence.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            sentence = sentence.Trim();
            while ((sentence[i] == ' ' ) && (sentence[i+1] == ' '))
            {
                sentence = sentence.Remove(i + 1, 1);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sentence);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

for some reason this code won't work if you throw 2 or more spaces.
But this one works, if you use sentence.Length , instead of size variable above.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sentence = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            while ((sentence[i] == ' ') && (sentence[i + 1] == ' '))
            {
                sentence = sentence.Remove(i + 1, 1);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sentence:{0}", sentence);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Why won't the first snippet work?

Comment: Take a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: None of your `Convert` calls are necessary, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `sentence.Length - 1` will increase or decrease the size of the string accordingly if you remove chars from the string. Whereas `size - 1` is fixed before the loop and it would give you `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` So in the first case you get the error. But in the second case your program runs successfully.

Dry run is the technique where you can see what would happen when your program receives some input and then step over every step in the loop like a debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!! =))

Comment: @Clarity: I'm glad that u liked it and u understood.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it breaks is this line in your first code block: `sentence = sentence.Trim();`

You are changing the length of your string in the case of added spaces, yet the loop will still have the size variable set earlier. so say you type: `'test  '` then size is `6`, yet the trim will make the actual size `4` namely : `test`. Thus throwing an out of bound exception when you try to access : `sentence[5]`.

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT: `int size = Convert.ToInt16(sentence.Length);` when you are setting the size you are getting the actual size of the sentence string.

It will cause `(sentence[i] == ' ' ) && (sentence[i+1] == ' ')` to go our of bounds due to the `i + 1` as this will cause it to go to `size + 1`
In your second code block you do this: `sentence.Length - 1` thus `i + 1` max value = `sentence.Length`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But even after removing sentence.Trim(); , the code still doesn't work =(
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in ConsoleApplication6.exe

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Because `sentence = sentence.Remove(i + 1, 1)` also changes the length of your string. Please please please step through your code in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, I won't make the same mistake again, and make sure my class mates also understand. Thanks again ! =)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first Snippet:

The first thing you have to notice is `sentence.Length` will give you an integer value, so it is not needed to convert it again as integer using `Convert.ToInt16()` you can use  `int size = sentence.Length`.

Let the input is `"this  is  sample"`, the length of string is `16` with two additional white spaces. By removing the first additional space the Length of inputString became `15` which means Last iterations of the loop will throw Exception, When you remove the second space then you will get the `IndexOutOfRangeException` at second last iterations. So this will not be a good approach to do this;

So better you keep the indices of the characters that needs to be removed, and write a second loop to remove them from the input string;

Comment: I'll surely try that approach, can't believe I haven't remembered that. Thank you so much!

Comment: There's also a flaw in his conversion. He converts a 32bit integer to a 16bit integer and then back to a 32bit integer, which means there's a possible loss of half the bits.